# How do I position JQuery UI Sortable item at mouse cursor while dragging?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm using Jquery sortable to reorder items. In my GUI I have a traschan icon where sort items can be thrown away. The trashcan is a droppable area.

Now, when the sort item helper hovers over the droppable area I change it's size to give the user the visual feedback that it's possible to throw it away. But I would also like to reposition the sort item helper so it aligns with the mouse cursor.

I tried:

```
$(trashcan)
    .droppable(
    {
        over: function (event, ui)
        {
            ui
                .draggable
                .css("transform", "scale(0.2)")
                .sortable("option", "cursorAt",
                {
                    left: 5,
                    top: 5
                });
        }
    });
```

But I only get the following js error:
**Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the `option` method on an element before initializing it as sortable.

try

```
element.draggable()
    .sortable({ cursorAt: { left: 5, top: 5 } }); // pass the options while initializing
```

or if it is not possible for some reason, try

```
element.draggable()
    .sortable(); //initialize first

element.sortable("option", "cursorAt", // then call option method
    {
        left: 5,
        top: 5
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `helper: 'clone'` option to your sortable instance. If, for whatever reason you cannot use clone, then the only way to fully solve this problem, and have the mouse cursor always be where you click on the item (instead of the item floating away), is this:

```
element
    .sortable({ ... })
    .find('.handle').mousedown(function(event) {
        element.sortable('option', 'cursorAt', {left:event.offsetX, top:event.offsetY});
    });
```